# MySQL retorna NULL quando coloca SUM sendo que não existe registros

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o código `SQL`

> SELECT SUM(r.quantidade_domingo) AS quantidade_domingo FROM relatorios
>   AS r INNER JOIN nucleos AS n ON r.id_nucleo = n.id INNER JOIN usuarios
>   AS u ON n.id_user = u.id WHERE u.id_regiao = '1' AND
>   MONTH(r.dia_domingo) = '11'

O Problema é que na tabela **relatorios** não existe nenhum registro e no `phpmyadmin` quando executo o comando, ele me retorna **quantidade_domingo** como `NULL`. Quando tiro **SUM(r.quantidade_domingo) AS quantidade_domingo** e substituo por **r.*** ele me retorna *"Nenhum Registro"* que seria o certo, pois no PHP fica retornando como se tivesse uma linha e não quero isso.

Comment: Não seria só o caso de você avaliar o valor retornado? Aliás, tem uma coisa que pode causar confusão aí, você está usando um label com mesmo nome da coluna, não seria melhor AS sum_quantidade_domingo ? Não que vá mudar o resultado, mas só pelo hábito.

Comment: Independente de resolver o problema, eu acho que acertar os JOINS ajudaria, de preferência organizando tudo com LEFT JOIN. Usar INNER é melhor apenas quando OUTER não resolve bem: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse é o comportamento padrão da função `SUM`, caso não tiver registros ele retorna **NULL** ou se não tiver valor também.

Você pode usar o  COALESCE + SUM para resolver esse problema:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(QUANTIDADE), 0) FROM RELATORIO;
```

Exemplo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5995/1)

Comment: +1, Ao menos com COALESCE ou ISNULL/IFNULL dependendo do DB, ele pode escolher um valor de retorno.

Comment: Usei o `COALESCE` e deu certinho !!! Para que ser o COALESCE ? (irei pesquisar também, mas para que serve ?)

Comment: É um valor padrão que você atribui caso o valor retornado for nulo, nesse caso usei o zero como exemplo.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli COALESCE ( aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) : Se aa for NULL, bb for NULL, cc for 278, dd for NULL e ee for 883, vai retornar 278. O coalesce retorna o primeiro da lista que não for NULL, ou NULL só se todos forem NULL. Exemplo de uso: `SELECT COALESCE( email_nfe, email_principal ) AS email_contato FROM cadastro`. Se o email_nfe não for especificado ( ou seja, NULL), a query retorna o email principal do cliente, senão retorna o email que ele escolheu para envio de nfe.

Comment: @Bacco nossa que demais!. Não sabia disso. Se soubesse teria poupado processamento em muitos projetos. Obrigadoo!